# Nested array operation for $all does not seem to work in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find documents where any or all nested array elements must contain at least the values provided. This can normally be achieved easily with the `$all` operator. For example here:

```
[
  {
    "words": [ "Hello", "World", "!"],
    "wordArrays": [
      ["Hello", "World", "!"],
      ["The", "Sun", "Shines"]
    ]
  }
]
```

The query `{words: {$all: ["Hello", "World"]}}` correctly matches because both are contained and `{words: {$all: ["Hello", "I do not exist"]}}` does not match. So far so good.

If you attempt the same for the nested arrays this stops working altogether. `{"wordArrays.0": {$all: ["Hello", "World"]}}` does not match. I have found similar questions why on nested arrays all the operators start to fail but no one ever can explain why and they just use `$elemMatch`. But I do not know how I would translate my "all values must be in the array" to an `$elemMatch`. And then how I would say

1. **ANY** of the `wordArrays` must contain "Hello" and "World" -> would match
2. **ALL** of the `wordArrays` must contain "Hello" and "World" -> would not match the data

I have prepared this little playground with the data in the hopes somebody knows how to achieve this.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/WSM2OGh-5vk

I would prefer if this could be solved all within the Find() stage, but if operations like this suddenly require the aggregation pipeline I am fine with that too.

Thank you!

**Edit:** My approach for **ANY** match does not return any matches, and I do not understand why `{wordArrays: {$elemMatch: {$all: ["Hello", "World"]}}}`. I read it as `wordArrays`: does any element match: array contains "Hello" and "World". And that should have matched the document

Comment: not sure if i missed anything. are you looking for something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/MEOrnq5zMuT

Comment: so basically it will return the doc if at least 1 of the inner arrays of wordArrays does not have ["Hello", "World"] as a subset

Comment: Ok, that subset approach looks interesting, but I wonder if this is the intended way to solve this "basic" problem. The aggregation expression looks rather expensive to me. But if nothing else works out this could at least an option. Will need to play around with it to make it explicitly ALL match or ANY match, return if one does not match is neither of which, but I guess half way there. Thank you

Comment: i'm not really sure if this is the best way. i couldnt find a way to this with elemMatch